# Why is my program not printing even numbers do while loop?

Tags: java, loops, netbeans, while-loop

I created a do while loop and even with the modjule sign its still not printing even numbers from the list, whats wrong?

```
  int w=1;
    do {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(w);
    w++;
    if(w%2==0);   

    } 
    while (w<=2015);

   }
}
```

Comment: Your if statement has no body. Google java if statements.

Comment: Also, w++ should be at the end

Comment: The code looks incomplete. Braces don't line up and even without the semicolon on the `if` it doesn't have any code. Is the `keyboard` being used at all?

Comment: Looks like you might need to read a few Java tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You code should be

```
int w=1;
    do {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(w);
    if(w%2==0)
    System.out.println("Even value : "+ w);
    w++;
    } 
    while (w<=2015);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon after `if` statement

```
  if(w%2==0); <- Remove this semicolon
```

And get or print even number inside if statement.

```
  if(w%2==0){
     System.out.println("Even valud is "+ w)        
  }
```

For even test, I would prefer bitwise `&` operation for performance.

```
 if((w & 1) ==0){// & is more faster than %
     System.out.println("Even valud is "+ w)        
  }
```

Comment: How does that fix the problem? Its going to print every number btw 1 and 2015 because the println() is outside the the if body.

Comment: that's even worse than before. before it didn't make sense, now it's a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

This was pretty simple and probably could have been answer in a comment, but here is a more complete code block:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // you never use this, why is it here?
int w=1;
do {
    w++;
    if(w % 2==1) 
        System.out.println("Odd: " + w);
    else System.out.println("Even: " + w);
} while (w <= 2015);
```

You should probably look at all of the parts of this code and make sure you see how it actually works and see where you were going wrong.